# Displaying supervisors who supervised 3 or more employees

Tags: mysql, sql

Employee TABLE

```
ID    Name        Supervisor_ID

1     James        NULL
2     Peter        1
3     Howard       1
4     Michele      2
5     Nicholas     2
6     Donald       2
7     Jackson      3
8     Anderson     3
9     Jeff         3
10    Will         3
```

I should get this at the end

```
ID    Name     Supervisor_Of_X_Employee

4     Peter    3
2     Howard   4
```

I tried doing

```
SELECT t1.employee_id
FROM  employee t1
      JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT supervisor_id FROM employee) t2
      ON t1.employee_id = t2.supervisor_id;
```

Doesn't seem to produce what I want

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the supervisor count so you group on the supervisor id like this

```
SELECT Supervisor_ID, count(*) as CNT
FROM  employee
GROUP BY Supervisor_ID
```

add a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 2` to get the ones that are 3 or more.

Oh... but you want the name too?  then you have to join back to the table to get the name.

```
SELECT E.ID, E.Name, SUB.CNT 
FROM (
  SELECT Supervisor_ID, count(*) as CNT
  FROM  employee
  GROUP BY Supervisor_ID
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) AS SUB
JOIN employee as E on E.ID = SUB.Supervisor_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Supervisor_id, COUNT(*) AS Supervisor_Of_X_Employee
FROM  employee
GROUP BY Supervisor_id
```

if you need the name you'll have to do an inner join

```
SELECT employee_grouped.Supervisor_id, employee.Name, Supervisor_Of_X_Employee
FROM employee
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Supervisor_id, COUNT(*) AS Supervisor_Of_X_Employee
   FROM  employee
   GROUP BY Supervisor_id
) employee_grouped ON employee.Id = employee_grouped.Supervisor_id
```

Comment: There is no column `Employee_id`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a self join approach with aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    e1.Name,
    COUNT(*) AS Supervisor_Of_X_Employee
FROM employee e1
INNER JOIN employee e2
    ON e1.ID = e2.Supervisor_ID
GROUP BY
    e1.Name
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 2;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo